# Why is my application hanging when ran from the webserver?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, pstools

I'm using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to run a command line program without having to wait for it to finish to report back to the script that ran it. I'm using a PHP script to run it. When I run the PHP script manually on the server, everything runs fine and works as expected. However, when I run the PHP script through the webserver using a GET request to send my parameters, it just hangs. Specifically, it hangs at the `exec()` that initiates the `psexec` command. Just hangs and hangs forever, until Apache sends out a `max execution time` error. Why is it hanging, and how can I fix it?

Operating system is Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `psexec /accepteula` in your script.

Comment: Why is it always something so simple?! Thank you so much.